# DateTime format in Visual Studio 2019 Locals and Autos Windows

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2019

Insane problem: Any variable that is a System.DateTime will not show me anything useful in the Locals window. They all show the same value:

Example: var now = DateTime.Now;

In the Autos or Locals window, now will show this value: Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {Date = {<Evaluation of DebuggerDisplay attribute reached max recursion count>}}}}}}}}}}

This is for Local dates, UTC dates, asp.net core, .Net 4.7.2, whatever dev I'm doing, it's the same problem. I can't imagine this is by design, and never had this problem in prior versions. I can't find any settings to change this. Does anyone know how to restore the value in the Locals window to a simple "{3/21/2020 8:54:23 PM}" format?

Comment: Generally,  the debugger will call ToString on an object to get the display value. The exception is if there is a DebuggerDisplayAttribute associated with the type. Does this happen for all projects (for example if you create a brand new console app and make a single change by setting a DateTime in Main)? If so, your VS install may be busted and it's time for a reinstall

Comment: Hard to say without more details, but unless you're doing something really weird in your code, it sounds like a VS bug.

Comment: Yup - all projects.  All project types (.net core, .net framework, winforms, console, asp.net core).  I don't use the DebuggerDisplayAttribute anywhere in any code.  Even a simple program like this will have the problem: 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

}

I'll try to re-install.

Comment: What version of VS2019 are you using? This issue seems to be fixed in v16.4.3. Here, it has a workaround: (Changing the DebuggerDisplay attribute in assemblyInfo) https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/802367/datetimenow-cannot-provide-the-value-host-value-no.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok figured this out, thanks to help from Oguz. I started down the path described in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/802367/datetimenow-cannot-provide-the-value-host-value-no.html and when I went to drop my shiny new dll in the specified path (C:\Users\%username%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Visualizers), I found a file named ObjectFavorites.json, with this content:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/vs/debugger-managed-favorites-schema",
  "types": {
    "System.DateTime": {
      "favorites": [
        "Date"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know where that came from, but deleting the file instantly fixed the problem.  The debugging windows are back to normal, and I didn't even have to drop in that silly dll file.

Comment: Hi Jason, since you have solved the issue by yourself, we recommend that you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and it is kind of you to help us create a better community atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to restore the value in the Locals window to a
>   simple "{3/21/2020 8:54:23 PM}" format?

This is quite a strange behavior in VS2019.

In my side, I create a `net framework 4.7.2` project, add `var now = DateTime.Now;` in code editor and then step into it, it shows the right time successfully as you wished.

[image]

So please try these suggestions to troubleshoot your issue:

1. delete any component caches under `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\ComponentModelCache`
2. use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start your VS Instance or disable any third party extensions under `Manage Extensions` menu to test whether it is caused by any third party extensions.
3. [do a fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in visual studio

**In addition**, if your VS is not the latest version, please update it.